# How to access variable across files in C?

Tags: c, variables, scope

I have a `file1.c` and `file2.c`.  If I define a variable in `file1.c`, and assign a value to it, how can I access this variable from `file2.c`?

How should I declare the variable in `file1.c` and how to retrieve the value from `file2.c`?

Comment: See also [What are `extern` variables in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/1433387#1433387)

Answer (score 1):

A.c:

```
int a;
```

A.h:

```
extern int a;
```

That's how. But don't. It's a bad idea.

Comment: I'd also advice against abusing it.. you can usually make a model where you pass these variables as function arguments. Helps keep track of stuff.

Comment: can I declare int a; in A.c, and use it like extern int a; in B.c, because I do not need a A.h for A.c

Comment: @user2131316, yes you can. Header files are essentially just copied when included in pre-processing. Using a header will just save you the need of editing the extern declaration at every file, if you use it more than once. But anyway, I advise you to look for a solution that doesn't require globals.

Comment: ok, thank you, but why do not, and it is a bad idea?

Comment: @user2131316, It increases coupling between translation units, for one. Exposing a global means other translation units know about your inner workings, how you represent data. And even worse, they can modify it without letting you know about it.

Comment: @user2131316, so for instance. If you need `a` to always be in a certain range, you can no longer guarantee that assertion. Since another programmer can access it and change it directly in another translation unit. It's a bit of an artificial case, but I think you get the picture.